# First 3D print made up of diagonal strands

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, underextrusion

Just got a Creality Ender 3 yesterday. Set it up and ran the dog test print. Photo below.

I used the sample filament that came with the machine. I'm not 100 % what kind it is, but assuming it is 1.75 mm PLA.

No matter what temperature I set the end and bed, when I launched the print, it would change to 200 °C hotend, 45 °C bed. Is that because the two temperatures are set within the gcode file? Do I need to set a higher nozzle temperature? And to do so, will I have to alter the G-code file?

Does the head need cleaned? I did try some blue ABS I bought, and didn't work, so I switched it to the sample filament. There was still some blue ABS in it, but seemed to be gone after a few seconds after the extrusion turned pure white. But might there still be some ABS clogging or slowing the filament?

EDIT: When I ran the test file with ABS, the material didn't adhere to the bed or itself, just created a jumbled bird's nest of spirals. Then I found something online that I needed to use the temperatures on the ABS spool. I set the temperature to 245C nozzle, 100C bed. But as soon as I ran the print, the nozzle went to 200 and the bed 45.

Is the motor that moves the filament moving too slow?

Is the head moving too fast?

Should I use a glass bed?

[image]

Comment: This is a very common problem lately, it is either related to wrong filament diameter (not in your case as is is a pre-sliced model) or the printer is set to volumetric printing. This can be changed through the display interface. See [this answer](/a/13480).

Comment: When I go to Fillament, I get: E in mm3: On; Fil. Dia. 1.750

Comment: E in mm^3 should be **off**! That will fix your problem!

Answer (score 2):

Based on [your comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/13542/first-3d-print-made-up-of-diagonal-strands#comment24210_13542) to the [comment of 0scar](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/13542/first-3d-print-made-up-of-diagonal-strands#comment24209_13542):

> When I go to Fillament, I get: E in mm3: On; Fil. Dia. 1.750

That's almost surely the problem. Unless the model was sliced for "E in mm3", this setting needs to be **off**. What it does is change how the printer interprets extruder moves in the G-code: rather than in linear mm of filament to move, as volumetric mm³ to extrude.

At 1.75 mm diameter, that's a factor of 2.4 mm³/mm, so you'll only be extruding 1/2.4 = ~41.5 % of the material needed. That extreme underextrusion will give **exactly** the effect you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for answering! That is exactly what I was aiming to find. Lately, the "reasonably priced" Ender 3 printers seem to have caught this issue just out of the box...

Comment: sounds like they use a messed up marlin latey...